# Run schedule function in new thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, schedule

I used the [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library to schedule a function every X seconds:

Want I want is to run this function on separate thread. I found this in the documentation on how to [Run the scheduler in a separate thread](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-continuously-run-the-scheduler-without-blocking-the-main-thread) but I didn't understand what he did.

Is there someone who can explain to me how to do that ?

**Update**:

This what I tried:

```
def post_to_db_in_new_thread():
    schedule.every(15).seconds.do(save_db)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=post_to_db_in_new_thread, args=[])

t1.start()
```

Comment: Show us your code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really need to update schedule in every task

```
import threading
import time
import schedule 


def run_threaded(job_func):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func)
    job_thread.start()



schedule.every(15).seconds.do(run_threaded, save_db)
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```